# laravel when page has / in url it redirect public/

Tags: laravel

I have an issue that if you write / after then URL it changes to public/
Example:

mysite.com/url (is working just fine)
mysite.com/url/ redirects to mysite.com/public/url

I have following .htaccess file which works for removing www from URL, redirects to https and show projekt from public folder. All these I still need. But also need fix the / issue. Any suggestions ?

```
# 301 redirect www to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# Force SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# SHOW FILES FROM PUBLIC FOLDER
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Your web server **root** must be the public directory. You should also not mess with [the default `.htaccess` file](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/public/.htaccess) that comes with Laravel. Anyway server configuration is off-topic for this site, which is about programming questions. [sf] or [webmasters.se] might be a better choice.

Comment: That is not possible due to shared server settings.
Also I dont edit htaccess files in public folder, but I have created new htaccess file in root folder.
It is not a server question. As i can not edit the server.
I need a solution that can work in this Laravel projekt

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: That line is already in htaccess file as mentioned.

Answer (score -4):

Check this file: app\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php